# How to block a user read branch's another user in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

> I want to block User A read branch's User B

! How i can do that in Azure Devops ? There is no option suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your are right. Consider to use forks: [Forks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks-overview?view=azure-devops). Then you can restrict read access to a new repo: [Set Git repository permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions)

Comment: Oh ! Thank for your help! We can't do it! I saw it here, in a comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/1028807/view.html